# Term for student who was thrown out of university?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a term or even a noun for a student who was thrown out of college/universite etc.?

I want to emphasize that he was willing to continue, but was dismissed permanently (e.g. due to severely breaking rules). He may never return.

- "Failed student" or the like implies that the student failed some tests, which is not the case here.
- "Dropout" seems to imply that he simply dropped out voluntarily, e.g. due to lack of interest.

Comment: There are rejects, and there are ejects. This seems to be the latter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Expelled*, as in *the student was expelled from university*. It's basically a crossover of the concepts of suspension or expulsion from high school

EDIT: I should probably point out that *Rusticated* would have been my first choice (had I remembered it) and it's actually the prescribed word for the concept. Moonstar2001 is bang on here

Comment: At the risk of "nit-picking": I wouldn't say it's a *crossover* of the concept from high school—it *is* the (same) concept: the act of a school expelling someone from (i.e. pushing them out of) the student body.

Comment: @TerryN - I'd say crossover because it's not the technical term. Rusticated, as moonstar2001 has it, is more accurate.

Comment: Someone can also be *dismissed* from a university, although I would not use it for elementary or secondary schools as *dismissal* is the term use for adjourning class at the end of the day.

Comment: I'll go with "expelled". Now that I read it, I remember having heard that tearm in the Harry Potter movies, which may be an indication that it is widely known.

Answer (score 8):

*Sent down* is the term used at the old English universities.

Comment: This is the correct answer for English universities. Used as in "He was sent down for his illicit drug dealing"

Answer (score 8):

Any of these:

[Expelled](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expelled)

[Debarred](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debar?show=0&t=1397119841)

[Rusticated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rusticated)

Comment: Rusticated is a very good one. Very apt. +1

Comment: At least at Oxbridge, [rustication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rustication_(academia)) is a temporary thing, not a permanent thing.

Answer (score 5):

The noun for the object of expulsion is the ungraceful 'expellee'.  I've only heard the term used once or twice.  I suspect it was an on-the-spot construction.  'Winnowed' may apply as an adjective if the circumstances are behavioral rather than academic.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with @kolossus that *expelled* is the preferred verb, the noun *expellee* just doesn't seem right.

Perhaps **[castoff](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=castoff)**, as in *After that incident in the Dean's office, he was a Harvard castoff.*

> a person or thing that has been rejected or discarded.

Answer (score 2):

How about "[dumpout](http://issuu.com/mm905/docs/ryar_look_inside/11)" and "[throwout](http://www.bowlandcentral.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-113398.html)" by analogy with "dropout?"

> E.g. [They produce large number of school dropouts, school "throwouts," and juvenile delinquency...](http://www.mocavo.com/Congressional-Record-Volume-108-8/539305/798)

Then, you might want to consider the term "[expellee](http://digicol.lib.depaul.edu/cdm/ref/collection/p16106coll4/id/498)."

[expellee](http://www.nationalreview.com/articles/260826/undisclosed-motel-6-illinois-david-kahane/page/0/1): a person who has been expelled.

> E.g. [The old image of catering largely for public school expellees and dropouts is completely out of date.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=PatXXNEWx_0C&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=%22school+expellees%22&source=bl&ots=u4QbVtUFgq&sig=nrC35sD-RmeoVXx9RZilV9JhARU&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=z5JGU-3UL6aa1AWQroEo&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22school%20expellees%22&f=false)

If you don't like any of those, saying "[expelled student](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsion_%28education%29) " or "[expulsed student](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expulse)" can work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

While I will not claim that this is the *best* fit I love the connotation of [anathema](https://www.google.com/search?q=anathematize&oq=anathemat&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.10496j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=anathema).

After he severely broke the rules your example would likely have been *anathematized*.

Answer (score 0):

The generic *suspended* or *suspension* would fit in this case. Those aren't to be confused with academic suspension, which is usually due to many failed grades or cheating.

Comment: Suspensions come to an end. The student has been thrown out permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **tossed** or  even **[defenestrated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/defenestrated?s=t)** (tossed out of a window, same root as the French fenêtre).

Comment: Spehro, *tossed* can have another meaning entirely... I refer you to FHM or Nuts Magazine.

Comment: @smci That will teach me to toss off a quick reply.

Comment: *<Insert obligatory Finbarr Saunders cartoon>*

Answer (score -1):

*banished* may fit. It conveys the idea of having being forced to leave .

Comment: I would not use this to describe someone being expelled from university.

Comment: that sound alittle too harsh

Comment: If you are told not to come back to a university for non-academic reasons often you are banned from the university so this fits.

Answer (score -1):

Would **ronin** suffice? It sounds kind of epic.

> [***ronin***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ronin) *2 : (colloquial, Japan) A student who has failed the entrance examination for the high school or university of their choice and spends the next year studying to retake the exam.*